# jQuery Slider Gallery: Scrollbar-Handle doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

I'm struggling with my jQuery Slider Gallery from http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery. After updating jQuery (to 1.5) and jQuery UI (to 1.8.9) the Slider doesn't work very well. The JS looks like this:

```
var container = $('div.sliderGallery');
        var ul = $('ul', container);

        var itemsWidth = ul.innerWidth() - container.outerWidth();

        $('.slider', container).slider({
            min: 0,
            max: itemsWidth,
            handle: '.handle',
            stop: function (event, ui) {ul.animate({'left' : ui.value * -1}, 500);},
            slide: function (event, ui) {ul.css('left', ui.value * -1);}
        });
```

It's possible to move the sliderGallery, but the .handle of the scrollbar doesn't move at all and it uses the width of the sliderGallery instead of the scrollbar-width. Last but not least there appears a little blue Marker in firefox (like it's an active status or something).

You can see what I'm talking about at: http://websitetestdomain.de/test/jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/slider-gallery.html.

Every help is appreciated, cause I'm not very familiar with jQuery jet...

Thank you very much,

Best Regards

Lucas

PS: I wrote some stuff with the jQuery 1.5 + Ui 1.8.9 which won't work with the older jQuery /UI-Versions, so I can't just use the older Versions...

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Slider Gallery does not work with any modern version.  I found one that is similar that does work.

http://www.ajaxera.com/jquery-updated-slider-gallery/